# Relational fixtures in Yii

Tags: php, yii, fixtures

How do I set up fixtures with relationships in Yii? For example, with posts can have comments, how do I refer to the post id in a fixture for creating comments?

Post fixture:

```
return array(
  'post1'=>array(
    'title'=>'My title',
    'body'=>'My text',
  ), 
  ...
```

Comment fixture:

```
return array(
  'comment1'=>array(
    'text'=>'Comment text...',
    'post_id'=> ???
  ),
```

Comment: Are we talking about relational queries here?

Comment: Not really? I just want to create fixtures (for unit testing) that have relationships like those in the production system.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know whether there is a dynamic way to do that, but the following should work:

Post fixture:

```
return array(
  'post1' => array(
    'id' => 1 
    'title' => 'My title',
    'body' => 'My text',
),
```

Comment fixture:

```
return array(
  'comment1' => array(
    'text' => 'Comment text...',
    'post_id' => 1
),
```

Comment: In case anyone is wondering, this does indeed work - **despite the documentation mentioning ```id``` fields being generated dynamically, and stating not to set them.**

Comment: As the order in which fixtures are loaded is determined by that in which the php readdir command lists the fixture files, *temporarily disabling the foreign key constraints* may be necessary.

Answer (score 4):

As far as I've worked out, you can use init scripts instead of classical fixtures. The [Yii documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/test.fixture) reads:

> It is also possible that we do not like the default way of resetting a
>   table, i.e., truncating it and inserting it with the fixture data. If
>   this is the case, we can write an initialization script for the
>   specific fixture file. The script must be named as the table name
>   suffixed with .init.php. For example, the initialization script for
>   the Post table would be Post.init.php. When CDbFixtureManager sees
>   this script, it will execute this script instead of using the default
>   way to reset the table.

So in your case, instead of having `protected/tests/fixtures/Comment.php`, you would have `protected/tests/fixtures/Comment.init.php` which does this:

```
// the $this variable refers to the CBdFixtureManager instance
$this->truncateTable($tableName);
$post = $this->getRecord('Post','post1'); // get dependent fixture

// define new fixture
$commentAttributes = array(
  'text' => 'Comment text...',
  'post_id' => $post->id
);
$comment = new Comment;
$comment->setAttributes($commentAttributes);
if(!$comment->save()) throw new CException('Unable to save fixture');

// add new row primary key
$pk = Comment::model()->getTableSchema()->primaryKey;
if(is_string($pk))
  $commentAttributes[$pk] = $comment->$pk;
elseif(is_array($pk))
  foreach($pk as $key)
    $commentAttributes[$key] = $comment->$key;

$this->_rows['Comment']['comment1'] = $commentAttributes;
$this->_records['Comment']['comment1'] = 'Comment';
```

Although I realize it's a very late reply, that should fix your problem. Since I got here googling, I was hoping I could help someone else who needs this info.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, even with the time delay! I hope it helps someone in the future.

Answer (score 2):

I know it's already answered but I think this is a better answer.
Yes, you can use dynamic fields for relations:

Post fixture:

```
return array(
  'post1' => array(
    'title' => 'My title',
    'body' => 'My text',
),
```

Comment fixture:

```
return array(
  'comment1' => array(
    'text' => 'Comment text...',
    'post_id' => $this->getRecord('post', 'post1')->id
),
```

PostTest.php

```
public $fixtures=array(
    'post'=>'Post',
    ...
);
```

Yii docs [CDbFixtureManager](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbFixtureManager#getRecord-detail)

Comment: I tryied that but it didn't worked, is anything different that i have to do on bootstrap or config? The _records in cdbFixtureManager is always null for me

Comment: What is "_records" ?

Does it work with hardcoded id ? If not, then its not related to my answer and you should seek help on creating tests and fixtures.

Tip: I think that the order in the $fixture array is important, so make sure the master table is included first (here 'post' is the first element in $fixtures then 'comment' should follow).

Comment: No other configuration required besides the one when using hardcoded id's. My guess is that you've misspelled something. For example cdbFixtureManager does'nt have any "getRecords" method. It has "getRecord" and it should return an ActiveRecord object. Maybe you've used the "->id" to get the id but it should match the id from your model.

Comment: I think I found the cause: CDBFixtureManager loads all the fixture files from the fixture folder in the order given by the readdir php function. To load the fixtures in a specific order you will need to add them to the $fixture array in that order and create an empty init.php file in the "fixtures" folder. Hope it helps.